# Getting unique group by values over 4 different columns

Tags: mysql, group-by, distinct

Ok, what I'm trying to do is try and get unique values from one table that span 4 separate columns.

For example, I have this below query which works correctly on one of the columns..

```
SELECT 
    rest.cuisine1, c.name
FROM
    specials
    INNER JOIN restaurant AS rest ON specials.restaurantid=rest.id
    INNER JOIN cuisine AS c ON rest.cuisine1=c.id
WHERE
    dateend >= CURDATE()
AND
    (specials.state='VIC' OR specials.state = 'ALL') 
AND 
    specials.status = 1 
AND 
    rest.status = 1
GROUP BY
    c.id;
```

Now, `rest.cuisine1` is one of the columns that contain the data. As expected this query returns unique values from that column only. The below being an example of what is returned:

```
12 Cafe
18 Asian
29 Coffee
```

There are 3 more columns in that table, those being:

```
rest.cuisine2
rest.cuisine3
rest.cuisine4
```

I could run the above query 4 times (one on each column) and THEN run the values through PHP to get only unique values from the 4 different result sets, however I was wanting to find out if I can get what I want all in the one query.

Comment: I edited it slightly, perhaps that help!? But I'll check out what you suggested above.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal Ok, this worked, however I had to change the select to `rest.id, c.id, c.name` otherwise I would get the incorrect  id :)

Comment: @MahmoudGamal Hmmmmm seems you removed your comment?

Comment: @KuyaJohn I have a working result now going from MahmoudGamal's answer. I will post it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer is based off of MahmoudGamal's answer he posted in a comment, which he deleted for some reason.

I used the below..

```
SELECT 
    c.id, c.name
FROM
    specials
    INNER JOIN restaurant AS rest ON specials.restaurantid=rest.id
    INNER JOIN cuisine AS c ON c.id IN (rest.cuisine1, rest.cuisine2, rest.cuisine3, rest.cuisine4)
WHERE
    dateend >= CURDATE()
AND
    (specials.state='VIC' OR specials.state = 'ALL') 
AND 
    specials.status = 1 
AND 
    rest.status = 1
GROUP BY
    c.id;
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
 SELECT 
    rest.cuisine1, c.name ,rest.cuisine2 , rest.cuisine3, rest.cuisine4
FROM
    specials
    INNER JOIN restaurant AS rest ON specials.restaurantid=rest.id
    INNER JOIN cuisine AS c ON rest.cuisine1=c.id
            INNER JOIN cuisine AS c2 ON rest.cuisine2=c2.id
            INNER JOIN cuisine AS c3 ON rest.cuisine3=c3.id
            INNER JOIN cuisine AS c4 ON rest.cuisine4=c4.id
WHERE
    dateend >= CURDATE()
AND
    (specials.state='VIC' OR specials.state = 'ALL') 
AND 
    specials.status = 1 
AND 
    rest.status = 1
GROUP BY
    c.id;
```